# Multiple UI extensions with the same method

Tags: swift

I want to write extensions for some UI elements, like UIView, UIButton, UILabel, etc...

But in case, 2 methods in 2 extensions are same name, swift say "Overriding non-@objc declarations from extensions is not supported".

And if I change to "@objc func", Swift say "Overriding declaration requires an 'override' keyword"

```
public extension UIView {
    func setBackgroundImage( imageFileName: String ) {
        let bgImage = UIImage(named: imageFileName)!
        self.backgroundColor = UIColor(patternImage: bgImage)
    }
}

public extension UIButton {
    func setBackgroundImage( imageFileName: String ) {
        let bgImage = UIImage(named: imageFileName)!
        self.setImage(bgImage, for: .normal)
    }
}
```

How can I do that? Thanks in advance
I use swift 5, Xcode 10.2

Comment: `UIButton` inherits from `UIView`, hence the issue.

Answer (score -1):

As Xcode says the only way is to make it @objc.
So change the code to:

```
public extension UIView {
    @objc func setBackgroundImage( imageFileName: String ) {
        let bgImage = UIImage(named: imageFileName)!
        self.backgroundColor = UIColor(patternImage: bgImage)
    }
}

public extension UIButton {
    @objc override func setBackgroundImage( imageFileName: String ) {
        let bgImage = UIImage(named: imageFileName)!
        self.setImage(bgImage, for: .normal)
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried your code before post this question, but not work for me. I test in UIView, and it work, but not work in UIButton.